# Show that $T: L^2([0,1]) \to L^2([0,1])$, $f(x) \mapsto x \cdot f(x)$ is bounded.

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, operator-theory, self-adjoint-operators

> Let $T: L^2([0,1]) \to L^2([0,1])$, $f(x) \mapsto x \cdot f(x)$. I want to show that $T$ is bounded by finding an upper bound on its norm $\| T \|$.

**What I've tried**

Using Cauchy-Schwarz we have
\begin{align}
\| T \|^2
& = \sup_{\| f \|_2 = 1} \| T f \|^2
= \sup_{\int_{0}^{1} |f(x)|^2 dx = 1} \int_{0}^{1} x^2 | f(x) |^2 dx \\
& \le \sup_{\int_{0}^{1} |f(x)|^2 dx = 1} \sqrt{\int_{0}^{1} x^4 dx} \sqrt{\int_{0}^{1} | f(x) |^4 dx} \\
& = \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\sup_{\int_{0}^{1} |f(x)|^2 dx = 1} \sqrt{\int_{0}^{1} | f(x) |^4 dx}
\end{align}
I am not sure if the next step is correct:
$$
\sup_{\int_{0}^{1} |f(x)|^2 dx = 1} \sqrt{\int_{0}^{1} | f(x) |^4 dx}
\le  \sup_{\int_{0}^{1} |f(x)|^2 dx = 1} \sqrt{\left(\int_{0}^{1} | f(x) |^2 dx\right)^{2}}
= 1.
$$
If the above step is incorrect, how can we continue or is there a neater way? Hints are greatly appreciated.

Comment: At points $x$ where the values of $f$ are larger than $1$ you have $f^4(x)>f^2(x)$. For example, if $f(x)=2$ for $x\in[0,1/4]$ and zero otherwise. Then $\|f\|^2=1$. But $\|f^2\|^2=16/4=4$. You can use instead that for $x\in[01]$ you have $|x^2f^2(x)|\leq 1^2|f^2(x)|$.

Comment: The last step is incorrect.  An application of Cauchy-Schwarz shows you that $$\int_0^1 \big|f(x)\big|^2 dx \le \sqrt{\int_0^1 1 dx}\sqrt{\int_0^1 \big|f(x)\big|^4 dx}.$$  You should get $\|T\|=1$ btw.  Use a *bump function* $f$ with support being $[1-\epsilon,1]$ or something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is easier than you think:
$$
||Tf||^2
=\int_0^1 |xf(x)|^2 dx
=\int_0^1|x|^2|f(x)|^2 dx
\le \int_0^1 |f(x)|^2 dx
=||f||^2.
$$
So $||T||\le 1$, and by considering functions of the form $n\mathcal{X}_{[1-1/n, 1]}$ you can see that in fact $||T||=1$.

Comment: I am not sure how I can see $\| T \| \ge 1$ with $f(x) := n \mathbb{1}_{[1 - 1/n,1]}$. I have calculated $$\| f \|_{L^2([0,1])} = \sqrt{\int_{1 - 1/n}^{1} n^2 dx} = \sqrt{n}$$ and $$ \| T f \|_{L^2} = \sqrt{\int_{1 - 1/n}^{1} x^2 n^2 dx} = \sqrt{\frac{n^2\left(1^3 - \left(1 - \frac{1}{n}\right)^3\right)}{3}} = \sqrt{n - 1 + \frac{1}{3n}}.$$ Now, $$\frac{\| T f \|}{\| f \|} = \sqrt{\frac{n - 1 + \frac{1}{3n}}{n}} = \sqrt{1 - \frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{3n^2}} \xrightarrow{n \to \infty} 1.$$Is that the way you had in mind?

Comment: Yes (stupid MSE doesn't allow 3 character comments)

Answer (score 1):

Actually, $\sup\left\{\int_0^1 \lvert f(x)\rvert^4\,dx\,:\,f\in L^2[0,1]\land\int_0^1 \lvert f(x)\rvert^2\,dx=1\right\} =\infty$. However, you can bound $\int_0^1x^2\lvert f(x)\rvert^2\,dx$ with another instance of Holder's inequality (case $p=1,q=\infty$ instead of $p=q=2$):

$$\int_0^1x^2\lvert f(x)\rvert^2\,dx\le\lVert x^2\rVert_\infty\lVert \lvert f\rvert^2\rVert_1=\lVert f\rVert^2$$

where $\lVert \bullet\rVert_\infty$ is the norm of $L^\infty[0,1]$.

Comment: @ViktorGlombik I don't **need** those things. You are the one who suggested the first $\sup$ to be finite. That is not true: the inclusion of $L^4[0,1]$ in $L^2[0,1]$ is strict, see for instance the function $g(x)=x^{-1/4}$